# Can I pour concrete next to my foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation, fence, post

I'm planning to install a 4x4 fence into the ground by digging up a hole, adding some gravel, then pouring concrete in. Is it a problem if the concrete touches the foundation of the house? I've added a picture of what I'm planning (not to scale or anything).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concrete touching the foundation shouldn't be a problem, but make sure that you aren't constraining any of the services (wires and pipes) shown in the picture, and that you aren't butting up against the siding, potentially entrapping crud and/or insects.